# Dealing with indefinite integrals when using Least Squares Estimation

Tags: probability, statistics, improper-integrals, expected-value, least-squares

Given $n$ random variables $X$ where $X$ is Rayleigh distributed, we have the probability density function

$$ f_{X_{i}}(x_{i})=\frac{x_{i}}{\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{x_{i}^2}{2\sigma^2}} \quad \quad \quad i = 1,..,n$$

I have a data set for $x_{i}$ and want to write an expression for estimating $\sigma$ with Least Squares Estimation, by finding the $\sigma$ that minimizes

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}-E(X_{i})) $$

That is to say, I try to set

$$ \frac{d}{d\sigma} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{i}-E(X_{i})) = 0 $$

and solve for $\sigma$. However, when calculating $E(X_{i})$ I end up with the following improper integral

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_{i}\frac{x_{i}}{\sigma^2}e^{-\frac{x_{i}^2}{2\sigma^2}} dx_{i} $$

which causes a lot of problems. I am not sure how to get rid of the integral in order to calculate the sum for my given data set. How am I supposed to proceed in this case when using Least Squares Estimation?

Comment: What is the connection between your $x$ and $x_i$?

Comment: @MathFail That's a mistake on my part, it's also supposed to be $x_{i}$. It's fixed now.

Comment: You integral limit should start from $0$, not $-\infty$, otherwise your total probability $\int_{-\infty}^\infty  f_{X_{i}}(x_{i}) dx_i=0$, since $ f_{X_{i}}(x_{i})$ is an odd function on $(-\infty, \infty)$

Comment: The integral needed for the mean of a Rayleigh distribution is related the integral needed for the variance of a normal distribution centred at $0$

Comment: @MathFail $f_{X_{i}}(x_{i})$ is an odd function, but my integrand is $x_{i}f_{X_{i}}(x_{i})$ which is even. In any case, the issue would still persist if my limits were $0$ to $\infty$ as I would still have to deal with an improper integral.

Comment: @Henry could you please elaborate?

Comment: @JBoy $\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu)^2 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}\,dx = \sigma^2$ as the variance of a normal distribution. Here you want $\mu=0$ and you want to adjust the multiplicative constant and keep the support positive for your highly related integral

Comment: Just do integration by part, and it becomes a Gaussian integral. Can you try it first? @JBoy